# Is there a way to set min/max order quantity for all products based on a customer type?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have different customer groups and I want to set a min/max order quantity for all my products based on a customer group, Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a native feature in BigCommerce. The native functionality is to allow a min/max purchase quantity at the product level, regardless of customer.

There are, however, a few potential workarounds.

1. You could create separate products that each customer group has access to. You could then set the min/max on these products.
2. If you were to create custom fields on the product for min/max purchase quantities for each customer group, you could use these values based on the current customer. You would need to modify the following lines in add-to-cart.html, switching them for the custom field values:

```
value="{{#if product.min_purchase_quantity}}{{product.min_purchase_quantity}}{{else}}1{{/if}}"
data-quantity-min="{{product.min_purchase_quantity}}"
data-quantity-max="{{product.max_purchase_quantity}}"
```